# jQuery validation form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

im new in jQuery..
and now try to learn and create a form with jQuery validation.
Then, somebody can show me how to validate IC value.
I/C value will need 12 digit and only a number.

from code below:

```
IC: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 12
                    },
```

user will can input more than 12digits.
i want user can input only 12digits and only a number.
how can i do that .?

here a full code.

```
(function($,W,D){
var JQUERY4U = {};

JQUERY4U.UTIL =
{
    setupFormValidation: function()
    {
        $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: {
                regPassword: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                Designation: "required",
                IC: {
                    required: true,
                    },
            },
            messages: {
                regPassword: {
                    required: "<br><font color='red'>Enter Your Password</font>",
                    minlength: "<br><font color='red'>Your password must be at least 4 characters long</font>"
                },
                IC: "<br><font color='red'>Enter Your I/C Number</font>",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });


    }
}

//when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
$(D).ready(function($) {
    JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
}); })(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> show me how to validate IC value... will need 12 digit and
>   only a number.

---

Use `required: true`, `number: true`, and `rangelength: [12, 12]` to require only a 12-digit number.  See [documentation for a list of all methods/rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods).

```
rules: {
    IC: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        rangelength: [12, 12]
    }
},
```

**[Working Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Aw/1/)**

http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Aw/1/